# Concatenate and remove brackets

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql, string-concatenation

I am using Postgres and this is the return of a plpgsql function.

```
point = x||','||y;
```

The following is the output I get from the function:

```
"(14.5084692510445),(35.8988013191481)"
```

The thing is that I would like to output the values surrounded without any brackets. Is it possible to be done?

Comment: the simple concatenation should work fine - we need to see how x and y are constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the data types involved, which are missing in your question.

For string types use [`trim()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL):

```
SELECT trim (x, '()') || ',' || trim (y, '()')
```

To provide for potential `NULL` values, you may want to use [`concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) in addition:

```
SELECT concat_ws(',', trim (x, '()'), trim (y, '()'))
```

`concat_ws()` was introduced with Postgres 9.1.